# Read a line from a text file and interpret the character it's on?

Tags: c#

I want to read one line of a text file, one character at a time. I figure it'd be something like this:

```
string[] acct = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Accts.txt");
for (int i = 0; i >= acct[line].Length; i++)
{

}
```

But I don't know what goes in the for loop. I want to read each character, and if it's a specific character have it do something else.

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here, as we don't know what `line` is, but your `for` loop condition is the wrong way round to start with. You *can* use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < acct[line].Length; i++)
{
    char c = acct[line][i];
    ...
}
```

But unless you need the index, I'd use:

```
foreach (char c in acct[line])
{
    ...
}
```

... and unless you need the index of the *line*, I'd use `foreach` for the lines as well.

I probably wouldn't even read them all into memory at the same time unless you really need to:

```
string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string path = Path.Combine(directory, "Accts.txt");
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    foreach (char c in line)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You may well want to split your code up to make it easier to read, however - write a method to process a single line, so you'd have:

```
string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string path = Path.Combine(directory, "Accts.txt");
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    ProcessLine(line);
}

...

void ProcessLine(string line)
{
    // Do whatever in here
}
```

This would be much easier to test, as well - as you don't need to read a *file* to test the handling of a single line.

Comment: Although I agree with last refactoring ProcessLine would be private so it wouldn't be testable at all.

Comment: @Peri: While I don't *typically* like doing so, I've certainly been known to make `private` methods `internal` in order to make them testable. It depends on how much difference that makes to the testability, and how concerned I am that the additional access will be abused. (I would typically add a comment around that.)

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what `line` is on here but since you can use `string` in `foreach` lopp you can do;

```
for (int i = 0; i < acct[line].Length; i++)
{
    foreach(char c in line)
    {
        if(c is specific character)
        {
           //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chars = File.ReadLines(path).SelectMany(x => x);
foreach(char c in chars)
{
    //tada
}
```